# TextView and EditText not rendering in Android layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I'm trying to create a simple game, but I'm having a problem with the layout. Below is my Xml code, I don't have any errors but when I try to run it the (text view_bet one and edit text bet two don't appear in the emulator, both of them should appear in the bottom of emulator. Any help is appreciated.

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#CD853F"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<ac.nott.Game
    android:id="@+id/game"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingBottom="1000dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stack1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/fiftey"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stack2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/fiftey"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/go"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/button2_text"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/betOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/go"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stack2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/stack2"
    android:background="#FFFFCC"
   android:text="@string/text4"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/betTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/betOne"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stack1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/betOne"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Info"
    android:background="#FFFFCC"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="#000000" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/go"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stack1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: change the RelativeLayout with LinearLayout

Comment: thankyou @OussemaAroua but now all of them rendering

Comment: make your note more clear please

Comment: @OussemaAroua thank you so much dear, l just added  (android:layout_above) for textview, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these two. `android:layout_alignBottom` means the bottom of the views will be in the same plus, thus likely to overlap.  You probably wanted `android:layout_above`

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/betOne"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@id/go"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stack2"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/stack2"
android:background="#FFFFCC"
android:text="@string/text4"
android:textColor="#000000" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/betTwo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@id/betOne"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stack1"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/betOne"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Info"
android:background="#FFFFCC"
android:inputType="text"
android:textColor="#000000" />
```